# Opening a password-protected website from servlet

Tags: java, security, networking, web, password-protection

The scenario is intended user will access the servlet (e.g [http://*someip*/myservlet](http://someip/myservlet)) which in turn **authenticates** a password protected website (e.g. [mysite.com](http://mysite.com) - which is hosted on IIS server with *Use Windows authentication* enabled) **implicitly and then opens** that [mysite.com](http://mysite.com) – so that:

1. target users will not get prompt for username & password as he will go through the servlet(hosted on some server like tomcat)
2. any other user accessing [link text](http://mysite.com) will not be able to access without knowing credentials

The requirement is
(**it has to open that website not fetch the content** as [mysite.com](http://mysite.com) has dynamic functionality in it)

**Is it possible in Java (HttpURLConnection) ??**

any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To be sure I understood your need, here is a summary :
you want a given user A to connect on your first server Server1.domain1.com, that would connect (from inside the java server) on a second server server2.domain2.com (currently under IIS). Then server1 would forward user to server2 web page, the challenge being avoiding any authentication popup.

The root problem is to transmit, from the server1 to the client browser, then from client browser to server2, the authentication ticket that server1 got from server2.

It is not specifically a java problem but more a global WEB problem. Indeed the only information received by server2 to identify client user is in the http flow, in short words the IP adress, the URL, and cookies.

Cookies is a dead end if server1 and server2 are not the same domain (see RFC 2109 : http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt), as browser would send cookies to a server of a given domain only if the cookie was returned from a server (the same or another) of the SAME domain.

So the answer is a two step process :

- first, server1 should get a sessionID from server2, probably through submitting a http request with appropriate credentials (basic-auth ? form fields ? or worst, "Windows like domain auth" ?). For this step, I suggest using apache httpclient library.
- Second, server1 should forward client user to an appropriate URL of server2, that would include the sessionID as an argument. It requires that server2 offers such a possibility to get in.

At first sight I see no other simple solution.

Comment: Hi zim2001, Thanx for you response. It may seem that practically its not possible but I have seen someone doing this. In that case the Server1 was a 'vignette portal app' where in one of its page the URL & credentials of Server2 can be configured and then users requesting server1 page were being served with server2 page whereas the address bar still showed server1 page URL (basically a forward).

How is this possible ?

Comment: I would guess that such a behavior requires a completely different approach; instead of forwarding client to server2, server1 "proxyes" server2 pages. But the huge difference with classical proxies, that works at the http protocol level, is that here the proxy works at the "html" level. Generally it requires html rewriting, a tricky and awful and incomplete approach (I experienced that a couple of years ago with the "gateway" component of Sun Portal Server).

Answer (score 1):

It seems the functionality you like to implement is covered by [HTTP reverse proxies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy).
This kind of proxy will "mirror" some site site1.domain1.com at another location like site2.domain2.com

Most common use-cases are that site1 is not pubic and the reverse proxy will act as a gateway, load balancer, SSL gateway or similar.

For implementation in Java: I also recommend the [Apache HTTP client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) library. And it's possible to use NTLM authentication with this client lib.

Answer (score 0):

The built in HTTPURLConnection might be not enough if you *really* want to implement this kind of request forwarding. Try the Apache [HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) which has ample of customization options. You could also look for TCP forward solutions or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986171/redirecting-from-own-java-server-to-tomcat).

Comment: TCP port forwarding only works, as long as the forwarded content is independent of the TCP connetion context. With HTTP this breaks at some places: 

The Host-Header will be wrong, so that the origin server may reject the request. Links in HTML content must be relative to keep working. HTTPS does not work.

Apart from this, its surprising how easy a TCP port forwarder can mimic a reverse proxy for simple web applications.